# Не осуществляется вход на сайт AngleSharp

Tags: c#, http, anglesharp

Использую для авторизации библиотеку AngleSharp, на все сайты, до этого я успешно заходил используя следующий алгоритм (естественно другие адреса сайтов), а на почту mail.ru не получается сделать вход.

```
class Program
{
    const string sourceToSite = "https://mail.ru/";
    const string sourceToTarget = "https://e.mail.ru/messages/inbox/";

    static async void QueryToOrders()
    {
        var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader().WithCookies();
        var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
        await context.OpenAsync(sourceToSite);
        var check = context.Active.QuerySelector<IHtmlFormElement>("form#Auth").SubmitAsync(new { Login = EMAIL + "@mail.ru", Password = PASSWORD }).Result;
        var msgs = await context.OpenAsync(sourceToTarget);
    }
}
```

Пробовал указывать заведомо ложный пароль/email было наглядно видно, что ответ есть

```
title = "Авторизация"
baseUrl =  https://account.mail.ru/login?email=mymail13123%40mail.ru&fail=1&from=splash
```

То есть пароль неправильный и mail.ru перебрасывает на страницу неверный пароль

А при правильном вводе данных почему-то не происходит переход, а выбрасывает на страницу ввода логина пароля

```
title = "Вход - Почта Mail.Ru"
baseUrl = https://e.mail.ru/login
```

Подскажите в чем дело?

Comment: Судя по всему вам нужно авторизовываться сразу на e.mail.ru, а не на основном домене - это раз. Второе - на e.mail.ru форма появляется не сразу, так что понадобится `.WithJavaScript()`